# How do I access the rw "branch" (as in "aufs branch") of an overlay mount?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, aufs

According to `/etc/mtab`, my live CD system uses an overlay mount [`/cow / overlay`]. I can easily browse the `/rofs` mount [`/dev/loop1 /rofs squashfs`]. How do I get a `/rwfs` mount? That is, how do I access the rw component of the overlay mount? Or what is its real name (path) if it's already mounted?

Comment: What `mount` shows?